# How should I connect the microwave exhaust flange to the roof venting when they don't align?

Tags: hvac, kitchens, microhood

I am installing my OTR microwave. The venting looks like it will definitely not align.

In any case, can I simply use flexible venting to connect the microwave flange to the roof venting?

Also, I need to extend the boot to allow for the damper to close (nobody does this on the YouTube videos). Do I need to create this, or can this be found in stores? I could not find anything like it a Home Depot the other day. I guess I could use a longer boot (say 4" instead of the "required" 3.25").

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would find a boot that covers the cabinet opening and install that, then see where you stand. A bit of flex duct may be a good solution (the semi-rigid kind, not the cheap foil junk), but a side-offset boot may line up perfectly. This one looks like what I have in mind, though the offset may be an illusion:

[image]

<sub>Image courtesy of Home Depot</sub>

Be aware that such a boot should slip over the flange on the microwave, eliminating contact between the exhaust and the wood of the cabinet.

Comment: I think the offset is correct, 'cause you need to go from the back of the cabinet (the microwave exhaust) to the center-top of the cabinet where the round duct comes down.  See my top picture here: https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/209345/is-it-viable-to-vent-a-range-hood-back-into-the-kitchen

Comment: Agreed;  or start with a  couple round  sections of the type which rotate one end relative to the other, then finish with a round-to-rect adapter,  assuming there's room for all that.  Otherwise, it's a minor sheet-metal job to build a custom offset.

Comment: I have never worked with sheet metal! I also need a minimum 3" extension piece to allow for the damper to close. I guess those are not off the shelf? Thought this would be a simple problem.

Comment: Yeah, that's why most such ducts are rectangular all the way up to the ceiling.

Answer (score 5):

I had the exact same problem. I used a 3.5" x 10" rectangular duct to go up through the cabinet into the attic. In the attic, I used a rectangular to 6" round adapter, then 2 adjustable elbows to get the right offset and angle to line up with the roof vent, and a straight pipe from the elbows to go up through the roof.  Bonus... I still have enough space in the cabinet to use it for storage.

I wouldn't recommend flex duct because all the ridges will collect airborne grease being sucked up from the stove.
[image]